# Combine MongoDb clients: pyMongo and MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

In my web application, I use `Flask` as framework and `MongoDB` as persistent layer. There are multiple libraries to connect to `MongoDB`. I am currently using the low-level lib `pyMongo`. However, I would like to combine it with `MongoEngine` for some models.

The only approach I see is to create an instance of both clients. This looks a big doggy. Is there a simpler way to combine these libraries (`pyMongo`, `MongoEngine`) such that they use the same database (with different collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its currently not possible to use an existing `Pymongo` client to connect `MongoEngine` but you can do the opposite; if you connect MongoEngine, you can retrieve its underlying pymongo client or database instances.

```py
from mongoengine import connect, get_db, Document, StringField

conn = connect()    # connects to the default "test" database on localhost:27017

print(conn)    # pymongo.MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary())

db = get_db()  # pymongo.Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary()), u'test')
print(db)

class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()


coll = Person._get_collection()
print(coll)    # pymongo.Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary()), u'test'), u'person')
```