# Is it possible to query the last element of an array using MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to query the last element of a list in a Mongo document using MongoEngine.
I can write a raw query to do this but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it without resorting to that.

So for example, while
`X.objects(some_list__val='Test Value')` would return any objects which have some list element such that val=='Test Value', I'd like for it to only return those objects where val=='Test Value' in the final element of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` or (from MongoDB 5.0 and later) `$last` :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient(port=27019)['mydatabase']
col = db['mycollection']
col.delete_many(({}))

col.insert_many([{'record': [1, 2, 3]},
                 {'record': [2, 3, 4]},
                 {'record': [3, 4, 5]}])

item_to_find = 4

agg = col.aggregate([
    {'$project': {'record': '$record', 'last': {'$arrayElemAt': ["$record", -1]}}},
    {'$match': {'last': item_to_find}}
])

print(list(agg))

agg = col.aggregate([
    {'$project': {'record': '$record', 'last': {'$last': "$record"}}},
    {'$match': {'last': item_to_find}}
])

print(list(agg))
```

prints:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('6537065c5c20464e8749e8e5'), 'record': [2, 3, 4], 'last': 4}]
[{'_id': ObjectId('6537065c5c20464e8749e8e5'), 'record': [2, 3, 4], 'last': 4}]
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#mongodb-expression-exp.-arrayElemAt

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/#-last--array-operator-

Comment: Though this is not directly through MongoEngine, I am accepting this answer as there seems to be no way to do this directly. 
For anybody who still needs to use MongoEngine along with PyMongo, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641425/combine-mongodb-clients-pymongo-and-mongoengine